# Laravel 4 Routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, routes

How can I create admin specific routes in Laravel 4 
(Restfull Controllers):

```
admin/users/ =>  UsersController@admin_index 
admin/users/create => UsersController@admin_create
admin/pages/create => PagesController@admin_create
```

and how can catch any parameters in URL without add it in route file like $_GET

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you group route with a prefix

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function()
{

    Route::get('user','UsersController@admin_index');
    Route::get('user/create','UsersController@admin_create');
    Route::get('pages/create','PagesController@admin_create');

});
```

and to get parameters in route

```
Route::get('someName/{id}',Contoller@Func);
```

The Function has to be written like this

```
public function Func($id){
/**
*do the thing here
* $id is the parameter passed through url, you dont have to use $_GET['id']
**/
}
```